# perl script to print square of numbers side by side?

Tags: perl

I want to print numbers 1 to 10 and print square of those side by side. 
This is the script I wrote

```
for (1..10)
{ print $_,"\n" }
```

This is printing 1 through 10 but I want to know how to square and print side by side.
I have tried using exponential operator but don't know how to implement and print side by side.

Comment: `print $_, " ", $foo, "\n"` or http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html

Comment: How your output should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i understand your question correct, this should solve your problem

```
for (1..10)
{ print $_." ".($_*$_),"\n" }
```

Comment: You can use `.$_**2` instead of `.($_*$_)` as well.It also allows for easier writing of higher exponents.

Comment: Thanks JID. That worked. Your understanding is correct. I wanted to print the numbers 1 to 10 and print the square of each side by side. Appreciate your efforts.